# 400 Bad Request in Pycord on_connect()

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

So, I recently ported my bot to Slash Commands, since that's a thing now, but whenever I run it it throws `discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body`. Same happens when I run any command.
The code is [here.](https://github.com/CuboidRaptor/CRBOT2/blob/main/bot.py)
The full error trace of both on_connect() and the commands are [here.](https://pastebin.com/TcBUys2p)

Some people says it's because their message is too large, but I'm not even sending a message. The error gets thrown as soon as I execute the bot.

Comment: This is probably a question best asked in their support server.
Or use a better fork of dpy than pycord :)

Comment: Is Pycord not that good?

Comment: And if so, what fork should I use?

Comment: Hey Cuboid, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include an [mcve], also please post it and the traceback as a code block, not a link.

Comment: @SimonT Please state wyh you think that the problem wouldn't exist with other forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is basically in the error message itself:

> Required options must be placed before non-required options

You can't have optional arguments before required arguments, which is the case in a few of your commands, for example `mute`. By defining the argument `silent` with a default value (`False`) you make it optional, but then you add another argument `reason`, which isn't optional, which isn't allowed by discord. To fix this, you can make `silent` a required argument, by removing `=False`

Comment: omg just realized how obvious that is (happened when I moved to Slash COmmands)

Comment: So, I fixed some of these problems and pushed to Github, but it still throws the same error.

Comment: Have you looked at all of the commands? Also the latest commit on GitHub was yesterday, at least in the repository you linked in the question. And are you sure it's exactly the same error message? Or did some later parts of it change? @Cuboid_Raptor

Comment: I just noticed the updated code in the Dev Branch, you still have default values for arguments, for example in your `unmute` command. You have to change that in all your commands that use it. @Cuboid_Raptor

Comment: yeah, I thought I would've missed something.

Comment: Yay! No more errors. Currently, it still doesn't respond, but I assume I just have to wait some time. Thank you!